# grub load kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, initramfs

i was trying to install woeusb through aptitude. suddenly laptop crushed to grub 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3

i can use set and get following
[image: grub>set]

i tried the following:
    linux /vmlinuz-4.4.0-111-generic
    initrd /initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
    boot
[image: initrd boot]

and this is what i get
[image: initramfs]

if i exit:
[image: panic?]

i dont know what im doing btw.

how to boot back to ubuntu ..
i was running ubuntu 16.04

when i boot from usb i can see me files

[image]

Comment: This usually happens when there are filesystem problems or HDD (hardware) problems. I think you need to get an Ubuntu DVD/USB, and check the HDD health.

Comment: hdd is healthy .. from usb ubuntu checked the option check disk health